# How to fix "error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]" at HackerRank?

Tags: c, function, if-statement, max

*Okay, many answers are already provided, but I couldn't really seem to find the solution.*

**Our task is to find the greatest of four integers.**

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/functions-in-c/problem

When I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if(a>b && a>c && a>d)
    return a;
    
    else if(b>a && b>c && b>d)
    return b;
    
    else if(c>a && c>b && c>d)
    return c;
    
    else
    return d;
}
*/

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if(a>b)
    {
        if(a>c)
        {
            if(a>d)
            return a;
        }
    }
    
    else if(b>c)
    {
        if(b>d)
        return b;
    }
    
    else if(c>d)
    return c;
    
    else
    return d;
}


int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am returned with this error **at HackerRank**:

```
Solution.c: In function ‘max_of_four’:
Solution.c:45:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

But the above code does it's job **when run on Dev-C++ 5.11**.

If we use the function ***inside the comments*** `max_of_four`, and comment out the latter one, the job gets done as well.

If somebody could get me to know, how `max_of_four` can be tweaked to get the code to work aptly, I'd be grateful.

And what's causing the error?

Is it an error or a warning? If so, why is a warning being treated as error?

Comment: If `a` is less than `c` or `d`, nothing is returned. This algorithm isn't ideal though. It would be much simpler to put the numbers in a temporary array, then loop over the array.

Comment: Alright, @Carcigenicate . I get your method of 'loop over the array'. It does seem simpler. 
If `a` is less than `c` or `d`, nothing is returned. But the cursor shifts to next else-if statements which sounds to be the point of using if-statements. I couldn't understand how the algorithm is not ideal, could you please elaborate?

Comment: `else if(b>c)` is only associated with `if(a>b)`. The inner checks need their own `else if`s, or the outer `else if`s should be changed to `if`s so that they'll run regardless. That's what the answerer did, although a loop would still be much easier. Say you add a fifth number later that you want to check against. Adapting this code would be a mess.

Comment: @carcigenicate ohh... alright, got that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is not void and you use a `if` statement to return the value, you must check that every case is really handled. This is not ensured by the last else in this case because you use nested statements which don't have a `else`.

Here is a fixed version :

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if(a>b)
    {
        if(a>c)
        {
            if(a>d)
            return a;
        }
    }
    
    if(b>c) //<====== I removed the else here to fix the implicit
            //        else of the previous form that was not handled
    {
        if(b>d)
        return b;
    }
    
    if(c>d) //<===== Idem
    return c;
    
    else
    return d;
}
```

Note however that the nested `if` in you function could be replaced by `and` which would be more compact :

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if (a>b && a>c && a>d) return a;
    else if(b>c && b>d) return b; // Here the else keys are kept even 
    else if(c>d) return c;        // if they are not strictly necessary
    else return d;                // because of the return
}
```

Finally it would also be more reusable to write :

```
int max_of_two(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
```

Because then you can reuse it for any number of parameters :

```
int max_of_three(int a, int b, int c) { 
    return max_of_two(max_of_two(a, b), c);
}
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) { 
    return max_of_two(max_of_two(a, b), max_of_two(c, d));
}
//And so on
```

Comment: Thank you, @dspr .

The compiler displays exactly the same error.

And I don't seem to point out the change you've made in the code, could you please specify that? Edit: I figured the change.

Comment: Have a look on my answer, it's more complete and specific now

Comment: Alright, got that. And this method seems quite simple and easy to modify. Thank, you. :)

Answer (score 0):

[@dslr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64732644/14597561) has already provided with optimum answer to everything, asked above.

For any of the coming readers, what [@Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate) commented can be understood from the code below:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if(a>b)
    {
        if(a>c)
        {
            if(a>d)
                return a;            
            else
                return d;
        }
        else if(c>d)
            return c;
        else
            return d;
    }
    else if(b>c)
    {
        if(b>d)
            return b;
        else
            return d;
    }
    else if(c>d)
    {
        return c;
    }
    else
        return d;
}
```

The code runs smoothly on HackerRank, without giving any error.

And this is probably what [@Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate) meant by 'loop over array':

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int i;
    int arr[4]={a,b,c,d};
    int max=arr[0];
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(max<arr[i])
            max=arr[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Thanks everyone. :)